# Confused regarding the (dual) basis vectors of the cotangent space $T^*_pM$ of a smooth manifold $M$ and components.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, co-tangent-space

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold with $p\in M$. Consider the cotangent space $$\operatorname{Alt}^{1}T_pM = \operatorname{Hom}(T_pM,\mathbb{R}) = T^*_pM$$

Now, choosing a chart $(U,\varphi)$ around $p$ on $M$ determines coordinates $x^1,...,x^n$.

I know that having $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ as the standard basis vectors of $T_pM$, the differentials ($1$-forms) $\mathrm  dx^i \in T_p^*M$ are the dual basis vectors of the cotangent space.

Therefore any element $\alpha$ of the contangent space $T^*_pM$ can be expressed with respect to the standard basis vectors $\mathrm dx^i$ as follows

$$\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \mathrm dx^i$$

where $a_i$ are the components of $\alpha$ with respect to the basis $\mathrm dx^1,...,\mathrm dx^n$.

Now my question is the following. In one of our solutions to an exercise, the tutor phrased the above expression as

$$\alpha_q = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_q\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right) \mathrm dx^i$$

And this is also something that got brushed over in the lecture, but i don't see how this holds since assuming $\alpha_q \in T_p^*M$ to be a $1$-form, it can certainly be evaluated at basis vectors via $ \alpha_q\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)$ but what it returns is a real number, so (if i am not mistaken)
$$ \alpha_q\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right) \in \mathbb{R}$$

how does that make sense? The components with respect to the basis vectors $\mathrm dx^i$ are supposed to be elements of $T_p^*M$ and not real numbers, aren't they?

Comment: What would $\alpha_idx^i$ mean if $\alpha_i \in T_p^*M$ (rather than $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: uhh i think i see my flaw, the key observation here is that $T_p^*M$ is a real vector space, thus the linearcombination $\alpha_idx^i$ is supposed to have real valued coefficients $\alpha_i$, is that your point?

Comment: Yes. If $V$ is a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, then for any $v \in V$, there are unique $c_i \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $v = \sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i$.

Comment: Yeah, i obviously somehow forgot to consider that $T_p^*M$ is a real vector space, even though i know it, i didnt consider it and messed up. Thank you for the hint @MichaelAlbanese, appreciating your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the cotangent space $T_p^*M$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Thus any linear combination of elements in $T_p^*M$ has real valued coefficients.